# Is this valid Syntax to create character linklist?

Tags: java, linked-list, character

```
LinkedList<char> PC=new LinkedList<char>();
```

getting this error message when tried to run.

```
Solution.java:5: error: unexpected type
    LinkedList<char> PC=new LinkedList<char>();    
           ^
   required: reference
   found:    char
```

Can anyone explain why we can create the link list of arrays, object, and string but not of character?

Comment: `LinkedList<Character>`

Comment: where's your code that's in error?

Comment: This line seems to be OK. Most probably the error is in the line before. You should include in your post a few more lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

`Array` is an object, when `char` is a primitive type. As generics support only **non-primitive** types, you can create `LinkedList<Character>` and autoboxing will take care of packing `char`s into `Character` class.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a linked list of any Object. just not primitives.
you can't create a linked list of char\int\long\etc....